# Apache 2.4 Unable to recognize additional site - 404 error

Tags: apache, apache2.4

**Background**: I am running Apache 2.4.25 on RHEL 7. An existing web site has existed for years, and now I am wanting to add an additional unrelated web site running Angular.

**Primary issue**: No matter what I do, I am unable to route traffic to the new web site.

**Expected behavior**: Existing site continues to function on 8443, and the new site functions on 10443.

**Actual behavior**: Existing site listens on 8443 and 10443, but new site returns a 404 on both.

**File system locations**:

- Apache server: /opt/intapache/
- Existing (functional) site: /opt/cspgateway/
- New (non-functional) site: /opt/intapache/htdocs/ (Note: index.html in this directory is set to 755 file access)

**Current files**: http.conf points to a second conf

***httpd.conf:***

```
ServerRoot "/opt/intapache/"

Listen 8443

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User cachedb
    Group cachedb
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/opt/cspgateway/csp"
<Directory "/opt/cspgateway/csp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/intapache//cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/intapache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/cspgateway.conf
```

***cspgateway.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    DocumentRoot /opt/cspgateway/csp
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/example.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/example.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/chaincert.crt"

    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2

</VirtualHost>


Listen 10443
<VirtualHost *:10443>
    DocumentRoot /opt/intapache/htdocs
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/example.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/example.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/chaincert.crt"
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2

    <Directory "/opt/intapache/htdocs">
        AllowOverride None
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule csp_module_sa /opt/cspgateway/bin/CSPa24.so
CSPModulePath /opt/cspgateway/bin/

<Location "/csp/bin/Systems/">
    SetHandler cspsys-handler-sa
</Location>
<Location "/csp/bin/RunTime/">
    SetHandler csp-handler-sa
</Location>

<Location />
    CSP On
</Location>

CSPFileTypes csp cls zen cxw gif jpeg jpg jpe png sgi svg svgz tiff tif ico
Alias /csp/ /opt/cspgateway/csp/
<Directory "/opt/cspgateway/csp">
     AllowOverride None
     Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     <FilesMatch "\.(log|ini|pid|exe)$">
         Deny from all
     </FilesMatch>
</Directory>


## START SDS-POC CONFIG ##
<Directory "/opt/intapache/htdocs">
    AllowOverride None
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
## END SDS-POC CONFIG ##


SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
```

Comment: You have configuration in "3" places.  In the generic (outside any VirtualHost), and in 2 VirtualHost.  This is very confusing.  In the generic section, setup your directives that are the same for all sites.  Then everything related to each site should be contained inside their specific VirtualHost.  That being said, you should indent your configuration, so that each section is clearly identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided I built this configuration.

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/opt/intapache/"

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User cachedb
    Group cachedb
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>


<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/intapache//cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/intapache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/cspgateway.conf
```

**conf/extra/cspgateway.conf**

```
Listen 8443
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName OLD-example.com

    CustomLog "logs/8443_access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/8443_error_log"
    LogLeval debug

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/OLD-example.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/OLD-example.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/OLD-chaincert.crt"

    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2
  
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    LoadModule csp_module_sa /opt/cspgateway/bin/CSPa24.so
    CSPModulePath /opt/cspgateway/bin/

    <Location />
        CSP On
    </Location>
    <Location "/csp/bin/Systems/">
        SetHandler cspsys-handler-sa
    </Location>
    <Location "/csp/bin/RunTime/">
        SetHandler csp-handler-sa
    </Location>

    CSPFileTypes csp cls zen cxw gif jpeg jpg jpe png sgi svg svgz tiff tif ico
    DocumentRoot "/opt/cspgateway/csp"
    Alias /csp/ /opt/cspgateway/csp/
    <Directory "/opt/cspgateway/csp">
         AllowOverride None
         Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         <FilesMatch "\.(log|ini|pid|exe)$">
             Deny from all
         </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Listen 10443
<VirtualHost *:10443>
    ServerName NEW-example.com

    CustomLog "logs/10443_access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/10443_error_log"
    LogLeval debug

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/NEW-example.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/NEW-example.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/NEW-chaincert.crt"
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2

    DocumentRoot /opt/intapache/htdocs
    <Directory "/opt/intapache/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**What was done**

- Split both sites, each in a separate VirtualHost.
- Split the log files, one for each VirtualHost.  This helps debug what is going on with each site.  I also set `LogLevel debug` for now, you should set it back to something less verbose once you have something working.
- Set different certificates for SSL.  This can be undone if you really want both sites to have the same domain name.  It is possible here since you use different ports.
- All configuration related to each site is contained within it's proper VirtualHost.  ex. directories, or the CSP module.  I have a hunch that since this module was loaded in the generic section before, it was activated on both connections to 8443 and 10443.  From what I understand, it should only be active on connections to 8443, which I did here.
- Only 8443 has options `Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI`.  For 10443, it uses the "regular" options for serving html pages and their resources.
- `SSLSessionCache` was moved to httpd.conf, since this is a generic directive.
- I removed this directive: `Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf`.  No loaded module, no directive.

---

Doing it this way ensures each site is separate from the other.  Although I do not know what CSP does, I guess it should not be active for both sites, therefore it was moved into the 8443 VirtualHost.

Last point, ports 8443 and 10443 should be open on the server to allow clients to connect to them.

---

If that does not work, please start a new question and include:

- configuration files
- log entries
- expected behavior
- current behavior
- as much details as you can include!